# sql where clause - best practice: matching fields are entitled to be selected only if the other fields match, or are set to null

Tags: mysql

hard to be more explicit in the subject, need to explain the problem.

In this select:

```
SELECT `id`, `creation_time`, `roster_date`, `roster_type`,`roster_report_time`, `flight_hrs`, `rank`, `email` 
FROM `alert_subscriptions` 
WHERE 1
```

I have a fixed combination of the values 'rank', 'roster_date' and 'roster_type' to use in the where clause.
The problem is that I need to find who has inserted only a value in 'rank' and set other fields to null), or who has set 'rank' and 'roster_date' while 'roster_type' is set to null, and so on.

Whoever has a matching field is entitled to be selected only if the other fields match, or are set to null.

One solution of course is to put in the where clause all the possible combinations (in this case 7,eg ranknullnullORnulldatenullORnullnulltypeORrankdatenullORranknulltype.. and so on..) but I would like to find an elegant solution, also easy to update with more fields (this solution would drive me crazy adding more fields to the where clause, the number of combination would rise enormously!)

I'm sure there is a solution with some select or union or view, but when I get close to the solution I get lost and can't make up my mind.

I'm stuck, I need some external point of view.

Thank you everybody

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking. Can you show some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: I suspect what you want is to order the results by whether they match the different criteria, then use `LIMIT 1` to get the first match.

Comment: I want to sell a car, 2010, 2L, wagon. Mike is looking for a wagon 3L. Bob for a wagon. Luke for a wagon 2L. I want my select to show Bob and Luke. If in my where clause I put year AND size AND chassis it would give me no results. If I use OR It would give me all of them. The only way I have in my mind is to describe in the clause all the combinations. But I'm sure there is a smarter solution.

Comment: ok, so as I wrote before, to cover 3 fields combination I have to describe 7 cases, to cover 4 fields they would be 15 cases and so on.. is there any smarter solution?

Comment: Can you put that in the question. It's hardly obvious from what you've written there. It's not clear how those car attributes match up with the columns `rank`, `roster_date`, and `roster_type`.

Comment: the car example came up in my mind too late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if each criteria is `NULL`, and treat that as a successful part of the match. You can then combine each criteria test with `OR`.

```
WHERE (year IS NULL OR year = 2010)
AND (type IS NULL OR type = 'wagon')
AND (size IS NULL OR size = '2L')
```

Comment: Since `x = NULL` is always NULL, you could also write `IFNULL(year = 2010, 1)` or `COALESCE(..)`

Comment: so actually
    where year=2010 and size=2l and type=wagon and ifnull(year,2010) = 2010... etc.. right?

Comment: No, you don't need the first part, just the `ifnull` stuff.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel That would work, but I think the logic of it is more confusing.

Comment: @Barmar i suggested it in order not to duplicate the values. But i find your second solution is most clear.

Comment: Since the query is presumably going to be generated automatically from a form, I don't think duplicating the values is much of a concern.

Comment: Actually, I've decided that the `IFNULL` version is too hacky and deleted it. Just a bunch of `OR NULL` tests is the way to go.

Comment: Actually it's almost an exact translation of the question "if the other fields match, or are set to null".

Comment: Yes, actually while I was writing that, I almost realized that for the first time I was asking myself the right question :-/ thank you guys